# Run a Jupyter Notebook through Github Actions

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, github-actions

I have a repository on Github that contains a notebook I'd like to run automatically. I've looked at [this action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/run-notebook), which seems useful, but I'm not quite sure how my actions.yaml file should look, as I'm pretty new to Github actions.

Comment: What have you tried? How does your current yaml look like? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 2):

[Example 1](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/run-notebook#example-1---executing-notebook-with-parameters) and [Example 2](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/run-notebook#example-2---chaining-notebooks) sections of this Github action's author is an example of what your Github action workflow file should look like.

Since you're the user of this Github action, your repository will contain your workflow file under your `.github/workflows` directory. Your workflow action file can be named anything, as long as it's sitting in this location; i.e it doesn't have to be named `actions.yaml`

For another example, you can review [the workflow file at my repository](https://github.com/aslisabanci/algorithmia_issue_reporter/tree/master/.github/workflows), again under `.github/workflows`. This makes use of another action (and it's currently all commented out as I don't want to run it right now), but you will get the idea and it can help you generalize and understand what goes into a workflow file.